# How can I compare a loop value to an array value that is not sequentially the same?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a loop from 1 to 4, and I have an array which contain 1,2, and 4, but misses the number 3. How do I put or replace the missing 3 into 0 as my only thought to solve my problem, or get all the same values and then compare both sides? Because I need to compare both sides if it's same or not.

With this code, I'm getting the error: "undefined offset 3".

```
$a = array(1,2,4);
for ($i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    if ($i==$a[$i]) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        false;
    }
}
```

Is there other way to compare all those that have same value like

```
1 & 1 = true
2 & 2 = true
3 &   = false
4 & 4 = true
```

And display something like

```
1. true
2. true
3. false
4. true
```

Comment: you can get last number of array by end($a) and put it in the for function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that :

```
$a = array(1,2,4);
$flipped = array_flip($a);
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
    $res[$i]="false";
    if(array_key_exists($i, $flipped)){
        $res[$i] = "true";
    }
}

foreach($res as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.". ".$value."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most straightforward way is to use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```php
$a = [1, 2, 4];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) { 
    echo $i.'. '.(in_array($i, $a) ? 'true' : 'false').PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Here is a working [example](https://3v4l.org/Dco3b).

Answer (score 0):

The values in your array: `$a = array(1, 2, 4)` will not correspond to the `$i` in your `for` loop when you use `$a[$i]`, because the value inside the square brackets refers to the *key* of the array, not to the value.

An array in PHP is an ordered map, with keys corresponding to values. When you define an array of values without assigning keys, like `$a = array(1, 2, 4)`, PHP automatically creates integer keys for each of the values, beginning with zero, so in effect you are creating this array:

```
[0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 4]
```

With the code you showed, you should be getting an undefined offset notice for 4 as well as 3.

If your array is sorted, one way to check for missing elements in your sequence is to check the `current` value of the array for each increment of your `for` loop, and move to the `next` element when a value matches.

```
$a = array(1,2,4);

for ($i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    if (current($a) == $i){
        echo "$i: true".PHP_EOL;
        next($a);
    } else {
        echo "$i: false".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The array *must* be sorted for this to work. If it is not in order as it is in your example, you can sort it with `sort($a);`.